# Can i use the cd/dvd from an older mac mini as a cd/dvd for a newer one via a thunderbolt cable?

Tags: ssd, thunderbolt, mac-mini, dvd

I am not a power user of macs but i have an early mac mini with a dvd drive and a 2011 mini without a dvd drive, and wondered if i can connect the 2 to use the older mini as an external dvd drive and possibly storage for time machine?
Also i have put in an ssd into my 2011 mini and want to put on a fresh copy of the snowleopard o/s [which i have] onto the ssd using - if i can - the older mini's dvd to do so.
Any help would be appricated

Comment: Which version of macOS/OSX are you running on the Mac with the drive?

Comment: I'm running 10.6.8 on the mini with  cd drive and now have  10.13.6 in the new ssd on the 2011 mini

Answer (score 1):

The 2011 Mac mini can run OS X 10.7 through OS X 10.13.6, therefore you should not be able to install Snow Leopard. You should want to install 10.13.6 in a APFS container since APFS was designed for SSDs.

Comment: I now have 10.13.6 on the 2011 mini. My first mini with the cd drive is a 1.66 intel core duo with 10.6.8 on it. Can I use the first one as a cd drive for  the 2011 mini?

Comment: Based on the title of your question, the answer is no, because a 2006 mac mini does not have thunderbolt.